# ANTLR4 'error: package org.antlr.v4.runtime does not exist' on MacOS

Tags: macos, compiler-construction, antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to build a compiler using ANTLR4 for a uni project and for now I'm stuck. I tried running

```
javac TestPiinkk.java Piinkk*.java
```

and about 100 errors came up:

[image]

I've looked at some other questions, for what read its because the class path is not added, I tried adding it and it didn't work again.

[image]

I know there are other similar questions, but there is very little information specially about Mac, and I haven't been able to find a solution.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me, also I'm new to the Mac environment and also to ANTLR, so if you could give some advice on how to approach this project would really make my week.

So for example, I'm currently using VS Code and I tried using python as my target language, but I've noticed there is more information for java as a target language and I know that some people use IntelliJ, do you have any recommendations?
I'm currently reading 'The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference, 2nd Edition' do you know about other place where I can find more information?

Comment: This is because you haven't set the classpath on the command line for javac. `javac -cp "absolute-path-to-antlr-complete.jar:." *.java`. Note that you have to add the path of the .jar and "." (dot), the directory containing your source. When you run java from the command line to run your driver, make sure to again set `-classpath`. Unset any global environmental variables for classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your `TestPiinkk.java` looks like this:

```java
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;

public class TestPiinkk {
    // TODO
}
```

If you now try to compile it like this:

```
javac *.java
```

you'll get the error you previously got:

```
TestPiinkk.java:1: error: package org.antlr.v4.runtime does not exist
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
^
1 error
```

Just download the ANTLR jar in the same location as your `.java` file:

```
wget https://www.antlr.org/download/antlr-4.13.1-complete.jar
```

and compile again but now with the `-cp` (classpath) parameter:

```
javac -cp antlr-4.13.1-complete.jar *.java
```